# Trigger event for each object

Tags: javascript, html

I want website to change class of an element if it is filled. So, when user `blur`s out of an input field the program checks if it has any value and if yes adds a class. The problem is to pass this behaviour to each element in class' collection.

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
contentCheck = function(i){
    if(input[i].value>0) input[i].classList.add('filled');
    else input[i].classList.remove('filled');
};
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener('blur',contentCheck(i));
}
```

This works once after reloading the page (if there's any content in cache), but `contentCheck()` should trigger each time you leave the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've half-applied the "[closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)" solution to that code, but you don't need the closures in loops solution, just use `this` within `contentCheck` and assign *it* as the handler (rather than calling it and using its return value as the handler):

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
var contentCheck = function(){ // <== No `i` argument (and note the `var`)
    // Use `this` here
    if(this.value>0) this.classList.add('filled');
    else this.classList.remove('filled');
};
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener('blur',contentCheck);
    // No () here -------------------------------------^
}
```

---

Side note: `classList` has a handy `toggle` function that takes an optional flag:

```
var contentCheck = function(){
    this.classList.toggle('filled', this.value > 0);
};
```

---

**If** you needed the "closures in loops" solution (again, you don't, but just for completeness), you'd have `contentCheck` *return* a function that did the check:

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
var makeContentCheckHandler  = function(i){
    return function() {
        if(input[i].value>0) input[i].classList.add('filled');
        else input[i].classList.remove('filled');
    };
};
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener('blur', makeContentCheckHandler(i));
}
```

Note I changed the name for clarity about what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use anonymous function

```
input[i].addEventListener('blur',function(e){
 console.log(e);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/42etb4st/4/